# Zunimassas's Set With Fetish Sycophant Passive

Tags: diablo-iii

The Zunimassa's set bonus will allow your fetish army to last until they die.

The Fetish Army skill summons 5 fetishes. An additional 2 can be summoned with a specific rune.

The Fetish Sycophants passive is: When you cast a physical realm spell, you have a 5% chance to summon a dagger-wielding Fetish to fight by your side for 60 seconds.

Do the passive fetishes die after 60 seconds or do they last until they die with the set bonus?

Additional question: How many fetishes can be alive at once using both of these skills?

Comment: fyi its not 5% anymore, its 10% and it has to deal damage, that was a result of the last patch.

Comment: @z' they need to update their forums haha i got that straight from the forum description!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Zunimassa set bonus will only affect the fetishes spawned via Fetish Army.  Sycophants will still expire once their timer is up.

On top of that, there is a limit of 15 total fetishes at any given time.

There is currently a bug where if you spawn another fetish via the sycophant passive and you have a limit of 15, your oldest fetish will die (including fetish sumoned via fetish army).  Thus, if you spawn enough via the passive, you will no longer have any FA fetishes anymore.

This is important due to a few reasons:

1. FA fetishes have a built in force armor that limits the damage they take to a maximum % of their health, sycophants do not.
2. FA fetishes can have a different element than physical (some of the runes can turn their element into fire or poison) but sycophants are always physical damage.  This matters if you are stacking different elements on your gear.
3. FA fetishes are affected by gear affixes (some gear can roll up to +15% fetish army) and that does not affect sycophants.

Finally, if you recast FA at any given time, all your existing sycophants will immediately expire.

[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12091749472?page=1), and also from experience playing a pet doctor.

Comment: Do you think that it's a bug that sycophant fetishes take over your FA fetishes or do you think that that's how it's going to work forever? Do you think Because that's really annoying when all this happens.

Comment: @ChaseC its definitely a bug. It was not like this before the patch that reworked sycophants as there was no cap to the # of fetishes at that point. However I have no clue when they'll actually fix the bug. I do agree its super annoying though. Because of this bug a lot of WDs have dropped zuni set altogether as it lessens the effectiveness of FA when they get quickly replaced.

Comment: They have acknowledged the bug and announced the intent to separate FA an FS caps. They gave no ETA, though, and I don't even have the link to a post at hand to prove it.

Comment: I guess this includes fetish spawned with The Gidbinn as well?

Comment: @Bubba the gidbinn fetishes are actually even worse than the sycophant ones.  They don't benefit from +physical at all and can be 1 shot easily.  I wouldn't recommend using gidbinn at all.